# Cannot connect MySQL when I specify users' host by FQDN

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-sql

I'm runnning MySQL 5.6 on DB server and trying to conect from application server. (app1.example.org)

On DB server, user@app1.example.org is registered as user.

I logged in app1.example.org (CentOS 6), and tried to connect DB server.

```
[mylocalmachine]$ ssh phanect@app1.example.org
...
[app1.example.org]$ mysql -u user -p -h 123.456.789.012
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'user'@'111.222.333.444' (using password: YES)
```

111.222.333.444 is associated to app1.example.org in DNS.

When I add a user user@111.222.333.444 to MySQL and try above again, I can successfully connect to MySQL. But I don't want to do this.

IP address is a little bit hard to remember, and it sometimes changes because I'm using Google Compute Engine for app server.

I want to add only user(s) with host specified in FQDN. Is it possible?

I'm using Google Cloud SQL as DB server, BTW.

Answer (score 1):

You can make it open ,and use it through username and password of your db,else you just make your compute engine IP static ,so that it won't change .